# Pre-populate a textbox field with some text

Tags: asp.net

How do you pre-populate a textbox field with some text?  I tried this and it didnt work:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtTelephone1" Text="+"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What does not work? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: It works perfectly. Do you overwrite the text property in your cs file?

Comment: Martin, I want a "+" to appear in the text field. perhaps I have a bug elsewhere...

Comment: This works for me. It show a textbox with a '+' sign in it. Check your code-behind, if you are overwriting that value, e.g.
<br/>
txtTelephone1.Text = "some other text";

Answer (score 1):

For the text property, I believe you can specify the value like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTelephone1" runat="server">+</asp:TextBox>
```

give it a go

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the server side code.

Example:

```
txtTelephone1.Text = "sample text";
```

The code that you have provided will also work.

If this also don't work then anywhere in your code you are overwriting the field's value.